# Chromebook Crouton Debian xfce4 - Cannot change locale!

Tags: debian, xfce, locale

On the system described in the title, I am trying to change my locale to a UTF-8 one, in order to run the program Anki. However it won't let me, the commands `locale-reconfigure locale-gen` and any `locale-xxx/xxx-locale` command doesn't exist.

There was no `locale.gen` so I created one, it looks like this:

```
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

When I type in locale it says everything is `POSIX` except `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` which are all left blank.

`locale -a` returns:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

I've followed the guide on debian wiki and many other guides, all of which involve the use of `locale-gen` or a similar command which I don't have. I've also tried restarting with the new `locale.gen`, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command `update-locale`, and probably install a language package.

[This link](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Languages) has detailed step by step instructions to set the locale in Crouton.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this, it doesn't work, the command update-locale doesn't exist.

Comment: I think that you have to download a language package and to satisfy its dependencies apt will install the package that contains the locale utilities, package locales en Debian mainstream.

Comment: Hmmm, the language packages cannot be found... Gosh this is a pain.

Comment: The command to try should be like "sudo apt-get install language-pack-en"...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, it says unable to locate package language-pack-en

Comment: Looks like language packs are Ubuntu specific and [Debian works differently](https://wiki.debian.org/ChangeLanguage) try https://packages.debian.org/stretch/task-english

Answer (score 0):

> dpkg-reconfigure locales

Follow the prompts. You may need to reboot.